# Magento not saving Paypal API info

Tags: api, magento, paypal, magento-1.7, signature

My Magento V1.7.0.2 store is not saving the api info for my new paypal account.  I go into admin-payment method-website payments pro.  I input my Paypal API signature info click save.  I get the saved confirmation at the top of the screen , but none of the info I typed in remains.  It goes back to the default info.  Does anyone know whats going on?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot enable PayPal API in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954319/cannot-enable-paypal-api-in-magento)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a cache issue, Please try again after flush the magento cache.
After removing all the cache, you must login again.