# Cannot enable PayPal API in Magento

Tags: paypal, magento-1.9

In Magento 1.9.2.2 I'm trying to enable PayPal payments under System > Config > Payment Methods. I've entered the correct PayPal API credentials and chosen API Signature as the authentication method. We are not using a proxy server. When I save the config the 'Enable this solution' dropdown remains greyed out and the solution cannot be enabled.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the below? Taken from PayPal site.

OpenStep 1: Complete the Required Settings:

1. On the Admin menu, select System > Configuration.
2. In the panel on the left, under Sales, select Payment Methods.
3. If your Magento installation has multiple websites, stores or views, set Current Configuration Scope in the upper-left corner to the target configuration.
4. In the Merchant Location section, select the Merchant Country where your business is located.
5. In the PayPal All-in-One Payments Solutions section, click the Configure button for PayPal Payments Standard.
6. In the Required PayPal Settings section, do the following:
7. Enter the Email Address that is associated with your PayPal merchant account.
8. Set Enable this Solution to “Yes.”
9. You have now completed the Required PayPal Settings. At this point, you can either continue with the Basic and Advanced Settings, or click the Save Config button. You can always come back later to fine-tune the configuration.

Comment: Hi Amish, thanks for your reply. Yes, I've been through all the recommended steps from PayPal. I've even contacted PayPal tech support to  check everything's set up correctly in the PayPal account (it is).

I now think there's probably a conflict between Magento extensions/modules somewhere but wanted to check here in case someone else has come across the same issue before

Comment: Hi STL Graham, Have you managed to fix this? If so was there a conflict with another extension?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue after upgrading a Magento site from 1.7.x to 1.9. **I want to emphasize that I'm not 100% sure of the sequence, as I tried a few things before solving it, and didn't document the process.** But hopefully the info helps you or someone else in the future.

I found suggestions about running an SQL query to change one or both payment methods to active. I did this first, and wound up [setting both as active](https://www.cadence-labs.com/2015/06/magento-1-9-enable-both-paypal-standard-and-paypal-express-checkout/) using a statement like this - make sure to add your table prefix:

```
update core_config_data 
set value = 1 
where path IN ('payment/paypal_express/active','payment/paypal_standard/active');
```

Next, I think, I went to Magento System->Configuration->Payment Methods and edited the values in each - PayPal Payments Standard, and PayPal Express Checkout.

I still couldn't insert the PayPal account details in Express Checkout, but eventually realized it was just missing the UI option to expand the section; see below image, you can click that grey bar to expand it and reveal the account info. It took way too long for me to figure that out.

[image: Click "Express Checkout" to expand options]

Again, going from memory, but once I did that and saved it with the credentials, the "enable" option was back to "no" and could not be changed.

I'm not sure if somehow "Standard" was pulling info from Express, or if I had also just missed the collapsed box at the top of the "Standard" section, which expands to reveal the e-mail address & "enable" option. But it wound up getting me sorted out and accepting orders with PayPal.

[image]

See if that gets you anywhere. Good luck!